# Getting value from BootstrapCSS dropdown menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have made a dropdown menu with bootstrap CSS, which looks like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button id="btn_inputManhole_cost2_Dist" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle hidden" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> LC/HC
<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul id="ul_inputManhole_cost2_Dist" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href = "javascript:return false;">Low Cost</a></li>
      <li><a href = "javascript:return false;">High Cost</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the selected value using Jquery.

I try this:

```
alert($("#ul_inputManhole_cost3_Dist option:selected").text());
```

but I get nothing in return.
Should I define an id in some other html element than the ul?

Comment: I don't think using `option:selected` works on a non `<select>` element...

Comment: Thanks. You are right. But if I remove the option:selected then I actually get all the values of the ul list.

Comment: Yes, as you would. I'm writing an answer for you, just a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it isn't a `<select>` element, you can't use `option:selected` as in your example. You can define a click function of your `<ul>` children which will alert you to their value when you click it. From there, you can save a variable, change something, do whatever you need to do:

```
$("#ul_inputManhole_cost2_Dist").on("click", "li", function(e){ 
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

And a quick visual example:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Xyao61wXFU)